# How can I reverse the order of numbers in an array after modifying specific numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, reverse

This is the code that adds 4 to all odd numbers.

```
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 };
        int IncreaseOdd = 0;
        counter = 0;
        while (counter < 30)
        {
        IncreaseOdd = array[counter] % 2;
        if (IncreaseOdd == 1)
        {
         array[counter] += 4;
        }
         counter++;
```

This is the code that should display all of the members of the array in reverse order, but it is only doing it to the odd numbers.

```
counter = 0;

while (counter < 30)
{
 Array.Reverse(array);
 Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\t======\t\t{1}", counter, array[counter]);
 counter++;
 }
counter--;
```

Comment: Move `Array.Reverse()` outside (i.e. before) the loop.  You are reversing and re-reversing the array with each iteration.

Comment: Have you learned about the [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) loop yet? You can replace your `while` loop with: `for (counter = 0; counter < 30; counter++) { /* loop body */ }`

Comment: Welp, I'm an idiot. Anyone here know how to mark a post as solved? Sorry, created an account just for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse once AFTER applying addition to each item:

```
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 };
    int IncreaseOdd = 0;
    counter = 0;
    while (counter < 30)
    {
    IncreaseOdd = array[counter] % 2;
    if (IncreaseOdd == 1)
    {
     array[counter] += 4;
    }
     counter++;

    // now reverse

    Array.Reverse(array);

    // now print the results

    counter = 0;
    while (counter < 30)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\t======\t\t{1}", counter, array[counter]);
     counter++;
    }
```

Furthermore, I would upgrade your code like this:

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).ToArray();

for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = array[i] + 4;
}

Array.Reverse(array);

for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine (array[i]);
}
```